# How to type optionally empty objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

I'm looking for a way to properly type this kind of situations, where a var can be either defined or empty.
The way I'm currently doing it is through `Partial`, but then the outcome isn't accurate.

The greater context is MobX observables that start empty but get filled later on through networking. So their initial state is empty, but once defined, it's defined.

You can play around with it at [this playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEBEFMDMEsDtYBdYHt4FgBQCmQE7QCGAxpKAGKqqgDe2ooRAXKAM5L4IDmA3A6ABGreAFcAtoIL8sAX2zYQoAEJF8oEqlEAbACZDyReKEjiADkgCeoVIIBWkEkgB02K2fKr1AXkrVQAD50sjLY2pBIQmqsXqC+tCEKWEoURLDabKDQqOq2AG5oopn4kERs6JkAtKDYgmrORHGgAOQAjAAMzUlKALJEANY8oMigAApqsETaWbAAHpCZSAAW5LBsbKILADRCopHasAtMglqRy+Qc+KJOoiWuyWAAkvAcpfqo0MORUkOQyCvqKbTEoAR1EsBK73Upgslh2yGamSkmnER1QFjQ8CmoAA7ktYCQlsNMo1iBlINYOEQ8A03JYPCoiAAvJpUGhBcb4FBTAA8bIAfKEsOFvsyYsymgkZHUmQ0mm0AEwAZmavCAA).

```js
// Definition
interface Foo {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

// Bar could be an empty object.
type Bar = Foo | {};

let bar: Bar = {};

// Fails for obvious reasons - 
bar.a = '10'

// Making it Parial fixes the issues, but lies about the structure.
// Instead of it being either all required or empty, it's becomes optional which is a falsey state.a
type Baz = Foo | Partial<Foo>;

let baz: Baz = {};
baz.a = '123';
```

Comment: great question, docs are unclear about this...

Comment: So are you looking for `bar.a = '10'` not to fail? When you have **either** a full object or an empty one it doesn't make sense to create an empty one and then assign one property. This would make it a partial object.

Comment: @lukasgeiter This is just an example, like stated in the question, the context is a mobx observable that gets filled once a network response arrives.

Comment: So when you're accessing the observable, do you have code that checks if it has been filled already? Because `Foo | {}` is an accurat representation of an object that's either filled or empty, but it likely requires you to cast it if you want to use it.

Comment: It would also be useful to have some examples which should produce an error and some which shouldn't.

Comment: @lukasgeiter this is the example, i don't follow

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually in scenarios like this casting the empty object assigning, this way, I get a better types with small risk of using a property before the network request filled it up.

So I would type is as a full type with casting on the assignment of the empty object.

```js
interface Foo {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

let foo: Foo = {} as Foo;

foo.a = '10' // will work
```

Comment: This is one approach, but I don't like because it throws the responsibility on the consumer. 
It does work but the definition itself is wrong.
There might be no other options and then your solution is the way to go, hence the question.